# How can I close Daisy UI modal programmatically after submitting the form?

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

**Context:**
I'm working on a React component called EditModal which is responsible for displaying a modal for editing rows in a table. The component utilizes Redux for state management and React Hook Form for form handling.

**Issue:**

I'm encountering an error when attempting to close the modal after clicking the submit button. Despite pressing the submit button, the modal remains open. I've tried adding functionality to close the modal within the submitHandler function, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

**Request:**

I need assistance in implementing the functionality to close the modal after the submit button is clicked successfully.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { editRows } from "features/tableSlice";
import edit from "assets/pencilSquare.svg";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import editSchema from "utils/validations/form";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

const EditModal = ({ currentRow }) => {
    const rows = useSelector((state) => state.rows);
    const {
        register,
        getValues,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { isDirty, isValid, isSubmitting },
        setValue,
    } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(editSchema),
    });
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentRow && currentRow.length > 0) {
            const { priority, name } = currentRow[0];
            setValue("priority", priority);
            setValue("name", name);
        }
    }, [currentRow]);
    const submitHandler = () => {
        if (currentRow) {
            const { id } = currentRow[0];
            let priority = +getValues("priority");
            let name = getValues("name");
            const currentPriority = currentRow[0].priority;
            const isPriorityChanged = priority !== currentPriority;
            if (isPriorityChanged) {
                const isDuplicatePriority = rows.some(
                    (row) => row.priority === priority
                );
                if (isDuplicatePriority) {
                    toast.error(
                        "Duplicate priority! Please choose a different priority."
                    );
                    return;
                }
            }
            dispatch(editRows({ id, priority, name }));
        }
    };
    return (
        <dialog id="my_modal_1" className="modal">
            <div className="modal-box">
                <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                    <h3 className="font-bold text-lg">Edit</h3>
                    <img src={edit} alt="edit" />
                </div>
                <p>Press ESC key or click the button below to close</p>
                <div className="modal-action">
                    <form method="dialog" className="m-auto">
                        <div className="flex flex-col m-auto">
                            <label className="input input-bordered input-sm flex items-center gap-2 my-3">
                                <input
                                    placeholder="Priority"
                                    type="number"
                                    className="grow"
                                    {...register("priority")}
                                />
                            </label>
                            <label className="input input-bordered input-sm flex items-center gap-2 my-3">
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="grow"
                                    placeholder="Name"
                                    {...register("name")}
                                />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-circle btn-ghost absolute right-2 top-2 hover:bg-red-500 hover:text-white">
                            ✕
                        </button>
                        <button
                            disabled={!isDirty || !isValid || isSubmitting}
                            className="btn btn-wide btn-sm btn-primary"
                            onClick={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    );
};

export default EditModal;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I employed this code to manage the closure of the modal. Setting the value to false closes the modal, while setting it to true opens it.

```
document.getElementById("my_modal_1").open = false;
```

Additionally, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions for alternative solutions if there are more effective methods available.